# How to check two rows for two separate values and then populate each applicable value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am building a simple workflow. The functionality I am attempting to build is a column that will be used to show if something needs to be completed.

**Identification:**

- Column B is the column that needs to populate the value or multiple
  values.
- Column AE and AF are the columns that I need to check for those
  values and then return the value if true.

This is what I have for the formula in column B.

`=IF(OR($AE9=$G$3,$AF9=$H$3),CONCATENATE($AE9," ",$AF9),"")`

This issue is that I am only wanting the value to appear that carries "AUTOMATION" or "POPUP". The way I have the formula written, if either of those values are present, it will pull in the other value. In my illustration below, "Bates Crossing" is pulling in as well. I only want both words to show up if "AUTOMATION" and "POPUPS" are in the same line entered.

How can I adjust my formula to handle this?

[image]

[image]

Updated:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People often forget that IF returns a value, just like any other function - and this can be interacted with or used with another function, even another IF:

```
=IF($AE9=$G$3, $G$3 & " ", "") & IF($AF9=$H$3, $H$3, "")
```

Also, you can use *&* to join text instead of CONCATENATE.

Comment: Thanks! This works great.

Answer (score 1):

If you want both values from columns G and H to be true, and only then display the values from columns AE and AF, you should use `AND` function instead of the `OR` function. When that is not the case, then you evaluate one of the criteria cells. If it contains the criteria, you display it. If not, you display the other criteria. Your formula should be:

```
=IF(AND($AE9=$G$3,$AF9=$H$3),CONCATENATE($AE9," ",$AF9),IF($AE9=$G$3,$AE9,$AF9))
```

Comment: I don't need it to be if both are true. It is if one or both are true, only the true values will show up.

So if AUTOMATION is True | POPUPS is False --- only AUTOMATION will populated......additionally, if AUTOMATION is TRUE | POPUPS is True --- both will return.

Comment: @user1530279 See edit.

Comment: Thank you. That is almost there. However, it is showing all the values, even if it isn't AUTOMATION ($G$3) or POPUPS ($H$3). See my edit in the question for what it is doing now. Hickory Creek is working correctly out of all of those.

Comment: @user1530279 You could compare the values specifically with automation and popus. The And function formula could be `AND($AE9=$G$3,$AF9=$H$3, G3="Automation", H3="Popups")`

Comment: Like this? I tried it and it is doing the same thing. `=IF(AND($AE9=$G$3,$AF9=$H$3,G3="Automation", H3="Popups"),CONCATENATE($AE9," ",$AF9),IF($AE9=$G$3,$AE9,$AF9))`